# Filter pandas df with .loc[]

Tags: python, dataframe, data-analysis, pandas-loc

I have one data frame (df) and a list (posList).
I managed to "filter" my df with .loc[] thanks to this piece of code :

```
    df = df.loc[
                  (df['Pos'] == posList[0]) |
                  (df['Pos'] == posList[1])
               ]
```

But then I tried to write this instead (just in case I have to use a larger list in the future) :

```
    df = df.loc[(df['Pos'] in posList)]
```

But this is not working, and I got the following error :

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I learn Python by myself and I am relatively new to it so I apologize in advance if this is a stupid question ...

Thanks !

Comment: try this: `(df['Pos'].str.isin(posList))`

Comment: Oh thank you !
`(dfPlayers['Pos'].isin(posList))` did the job :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df['pos']` returns a column which is a `pd.Series`. If you a `pd.Series` in `list`, it will give you the `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`
i.e

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd                                                     

In [2]: ser = pd.Series([1,2,3,4])                                              

In [3]: ser                                                                     
Out[3]: 
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
dtype: int64

In [4]: ser in [1,2,3,4]                                                        
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-090fa5ec1b46> in <module>
----> 1 ser in [1,2,3,4]

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1477     def __nonzero__(self):
   1478         raise ValueError(
-> 1479             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1480             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
   1481         )

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

So to avoid this, and for your example, `df.loc` takes in a truth array i.e if you do `df['col'] == 'anyval' it gives you a series of True or False. In the above example it'd be

```
ser == 2
Out[6]: 
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```

So you need to have this kind of format for your problem. So essentially, what you can do is what @RJ Adriaansen suggested (actually without .str).

```
df['Pos'].isin(posList)
```